При сохранении элемента записать вес и габариты
Прошу помочь...
ловлю событие OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate или OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate
выполняю какой то код ...
в процессе надо записать габариты и вес элемента
  $res = Catalog\ProductTable::update(
        123,
        array(
            "WEIGHT" => 7000,
            "LENGTH" => 100,
            "WIDTH" => 200,
            "HEIGHT" => 300,
        )
    );

но значения не сохраняются.
На другом форуме подсказали т.к. происходит обновление элемента, сразу после обновления элемента запускается обновление товара в торговом каталоге и юзать надо события торгового каталога, но!!! если я буду использовать \Bitrix\Catalog\Product::OnBeforeUpdate или OnAfterUpdate, то при каждом изменении например кол-ва и/или цены будут происходить ненужные действия типа запросы в бд, вычисления и запись габаритов и веса.
Задача при сохранении/обновлении элемента записать элемент и его все параметры в том числе габариты и вес, как это сделать?

Вес относится к товару, а не элементу. Попробуйте через OnBeforeProductUpdate и OnBeforeProductAdd.  Что-то вроде
AddEventHandler("catalog", "OnBeforeProductUpdate", Array("MyClass", "ChangeWeightUpdate"));
AddEventHandler("catalog", "OnBeforeProductAdd", Array("MyClass", "ChangeWeightAdd"));
class MyClass
{
  function ChangeWeightAdd(&$arFields) {
  $arFields["WEIGHT"] = 999;
}
function ChangeWeightUpdate($id, &$arFields) {
  $arFields["WEIGHT"] = 999;
}
}

Должно сработать. Но не проверял :-)
